# Is there any way to create and work with Entity-Relationaship Dataset Model in R?

Tags: r, entity-relationship

I want to create and analyze data model (or, at least, data schema) of my table dataset in R.

Ideally, it should be an entity-relationship model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). There is not a single one package for work with ER-models on my radar. 
Optionally, it may be a relational data model. I saw some packages, but few good packages.

For example, for a table of three variables: time, customerID, orderID.

I want to make each customer an entity, each order an entity, link them by relation "belongs to" and link each subsequent order of each customer by relation "subsequent", using variable time.

That should result in data schema (aka oriented graph with edges of different types). Is there any standard format on how to create, store and analyze that "meta" information in R?

Comment: That may help: http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/ , https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/05/01/rstudio-v0-99-preview-graphviz-and-diagrammer/

Comment: Thanks, @M.Hassan. That would help create diagrams. I am searching for storage and processing tools of the data model (ER or relational). Those formats has their own protocol or representation in DBMS and, I want to find some way to create structure in R as if it was exported form DBMS.

Comment: DiagramerR use Graphize which is a graph language with syntax that fit many  models represented in graphs (it's not a drawing tool only).

Comment: In general, it's not possible to derive an ER model for every table/relation. For example, a relation with a composite key, consisting of two entity columns and a value column, has no clear representation in ER. Is it a regular or weak entity or a relationship? It also won't be possible to derive a full relational model if your database doesn't capture domains and dependencies (it almost certainly doesn't). However, I suspect you actually want a network data model. That, too, won't be possible in general, since network data models don't support composite keys and non-binary relationships.

Comment: @reaanb, thanks a lot! Network data model is not enough, as (as I understand) it support only one type of relation - parent-child. I want to make sense out of several types of relations. Thus, some kind of semantic data model is in need, ER at minimum.

Comment: @reaanb My database does not capture domains and dependencies. It may have weak entities. And, as I understood you, there is no way to define them manually (by human) in R, right?

Comment: I meant it's not possible to automatically recover a logical or conceptual data model from a table. Having a human do it manually might work.

Comment: @reaanb, as it possible to do manually, is there any infrastructure to do it? To mark up variables (domain, dependencies, relations) and to store this structure?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with any particular implementations.